# How to use get (getter) keyword in dojo

Tags: dojo

I am looking for a functionality like below in dojo class (AMD).

```
function () {
            var _foo = 123; // private variable
            return {
               get foo () { return _foo; }
           };
       }());
```

The advantage is once the value _foo is initialised user can't modify the value _foo or foo from the console. How do we achieve this in dojo class like

```
 define["dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/request", "dojo/_base/lang"],
           function(declare, request, lang) {
           var _foo = 123; 
           return declare("fooClass", null, {
              get foo () { return _foo; }
       });
       });
```

when i declare as above when we try to build the class using dojo build.sh it is giving parsing errors.how to make a value not changeable from debug console in dojo

Comment: There is not really and advantage with this solution, as if an user it opening the debugger console, can set a breakpoints at var _foo =123; and change its value any time.

Answer (score 0):

There is not really an advantage with your solution, as if an user open the debugger console, a developer could set a breakpoints at `var _foo =123;` and change its value at run time any time.

In your code actually you are showing an example of a closure.
A closure allow your `var _foo` to be hidden inside your `function()` so a developer would not be able to get that value within its js code.

Nevertheless you can still access it using the debugger console adding a simple breakpoint.

If you are interesting to use getter and setter for dojo, please read on.

---

The dojo naming convention to specify a custom getter or setter (in this example for an attribute named foo) is:

`_setFooAttr()` and `_getFooAttr()`

Example:

```
require([
     "dojo/_base/declare", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/parser", "dojo/ready",
     "dijit/_WidgetBase", "dijit/_TemplatedMixin"
 ], function(declare, domStyle, parser, ready, _WidgetBase, _TemplatedMixin){

     declare("HidePane", [_WidgetBase], {
         // parameters
         open: true,
         // custom setter
         _setOpenAttr: function(/*Boolean*/ open){
             this._set("open", open);
             domStyle.set(this.domNode, "display", open ? "block" : "none");
         }
     });

     ready(function(){
         parser.parse();
     });
 });
```

Comment: I think it is not correct, user can still modify the value "open" from debug console like var myPane = new HIdePane(); then user can modify the value using myPane.open.

Comment: @DurgaPrasad yes clearly, there is not really property private in javascript. A possible way you could achieve  it would be to use a closure. But even a closure id accessible in the debug console. What are you tried to achieve really?

Comment: @DurgaPrasad please read my edit? What are you trying to achive

Comment: we can achieve private as follows                                                   window.app = (function () {
    var _foo = 123; // private variable
    return {
        get foo () { return _foo; }
    };
}());
Once a variable is initialised it should not be modifiable in any debug console that is what i want. 
// --- accessing app from the console ---
// app.foo is readable from console, but not modifiable
console.log(app.foo);
app.foo = 234;
console.log(app.foo); /

Comment: Agree there is no 100% security but idea is to make tough to get the information. Our code is obfuscated so i feel debug is little tough. Problem is if i use get keyword the dojo build process is breaking. So we don't have any mechanism in dojo where we can't modify the value from debug console ??